# How to run the angular application i.e developed by using Angular CLI in VS2017?

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio-2017, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

Am working ASP.NET Web Application with Angular 6. For this, I created a solution/project by taking an empty Web Application template in Visual Studio 2017. With the help of Angular CLI, I added the Angular files successfully to the ASP.NET Empty project and the project structure looks like:

Whenever I am trying to run the code from VS 2017, then the Application won’t load **main.ts** file it only displays **index.html** content. But whenever I am trying to run the code from command prompt by entering the command as ng serve, then the application should launched successfully and load the **main.ts** file as well as display the UI/UX design.

So, can anyone suggest me what is the problem when I run the above angular application from VS2017 it won’t load the **main.ts** file? But the same application will work from command prompt using ng serve command.

Comment: Why didn't you use the Angular template that comes with VS 2017? Or, are you one of those programmers that needs to do things the hard way?

Comment: @Thanks Richards, But my client requirement is like integrate Angular components with ASP.Net Web Application.

Comment: Then I would suggest starting another application with the Angular template, have a look at how that works, and see if that will give you some hints on how to proceed. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Richards, The angular template integrated with .net core, but I want the Angular template integrate with ASP.Net framework

Answer (score 0):

- open cmd
- change directory or folder using `cd` command like `cd desktop` to your project folder
- put `ng-serve` on cmd and hit '**Enter**'

**OR**

- `npm run ng serve` use this command...